# Submit form with a link and include a name value

Tags: html, forms, submit

I want to replace the form button

```
<input type="submit" name="submitForm" value="Send" />
```

with a link.

What I have at the moment is:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('contact').submit()" class="button">Send message</a>
```

But I need include the name="submitForm" somehow.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a hidden input in your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="submitForm" value="submitForm" />
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to use data-attribute ...

```
<a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('contact').submit()" data-name="submitForm" class="button">Send message</a>
```

Then you can retrieve the name by ...

```
$(this).attr('data-name');
```